# Merging CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to merge a number of CSV files into a large CSV file.  I wrote a powershell script that successfully create individual csv files for each tag names.  But when added `Get-Content` at the end, I get this error:

```
Get-Content : An object at the specified path C:\HTD2CSV\Output_Files\*.CSV does not exist, or has been filtered by the
 -Include or -Exclude parameter.
At C:\HTD2CSV\extract.ps1:30 char:20
+ $temp = Get-Content <<<<  "$destinationPath\*.CSV" #| Set-Content $destinationPath\merged.CSV
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

But I already have CSV files in the Output_Files folder.  Entering `Get-Content .\Output_Files\*.CSV` worked fine on the command line, but apparently not in the script.  My code looks like this:

```
$currentPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$sourcePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Proficy\Proficy iFIX\HTRDATA"
$destinationPath = "$currentPath\Output_Files"

    @(
        "PPP_VE0963A",
        "PPP_VE0963B",
        "PPP_VE0964A",
        "PPP_VE0964B",
        "PPP_VE0967A",
        "PPP_VE0967B",
        "PPP_ZE0963A",
        "PPP_ZE0963B",
        "PPP_ZE0964A",
        "PPP_ZE0964B"
    ) | ForEach-Object {
        .\HTD2CSV.exe `
            PPP:$_.F_CV `
            /dur:00:23:59:00 `
            /int:00:01:00 `
            /sd:05/01/14 `
            /st:00:00:00 `
            /sp:$sourcePath `
            /dp:$destinationPath\$_.CSV `
            /dtf:0 `
            /dbg:0
    }

Get-Content "$destinationPath\*.CSV" | Set-Content "$destinationPath\merged.CSV"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Get-Content`/`Set-Content` for merging CSVs (assuming that you actually do have CSVs and not just peculiarly named flat text files). Use `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`:

```
Get-ChildItem '*.csv' | % {
  Import-Csv $_.FullName | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\merged.csv' -NoType -Append
}
```

or like this (to avoid appending):

```
Get-ChildItem '*.csv' | % { Import-Csv $_.FullName } |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\merged.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: As long as the headers are the same, then a simple text merge with ex. `-Skip 1` to avoid duplicate headers would be way faster. `Import-CSV` requires the creation of lots of objects.

Comment: Just added those to my script and I didn't see merged.csv show up in the output_files folder.

Comment: Just found out that Powershell doesn't understand the paramenter "Append".  I'm using Powershell 2.0.

Comment: Frode F. makes a very good point. Do all of your CSV files have the same header line?

Comment: The CSV files do not have headers.

Comment: @FrodeF. Assuming that both number *and* order of data fields in all files are identical: yes.

Comment: @vxs8122: I added an alternative. However, unless you're still on Windows XP (which you shouldn't) you can (and should) easily upgrade to PowerShell v3 or newer.

Comment: JUst upgraded to Powershell 4.0 and it worked (just had to add `-Header A,B,C,D,E,F` just before `Import-Csv` to make a dummy header)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It's computer-generated csv's from the same software. They usually use the same formatting in all files :) The fact that they doesn't even have a header makes it even better as you don't have to worry about only keeping one copy of the header when combining the files.