# Combining multiple .csv-files into one

Tags: csv, powershell

I got multiple csv files, all with the same header, all in the same folder which I have to combine to create one large csv file. Since every .csv-file has the same header, I guess using it once should be enough.

All files look like this (also delimited by ','):

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
Data1, Data2, Data3
Data4, Data5, Data6
```

Can you help out? I'm not very comfortable with Powershell yet, tried out different codes but nothing really helped me out.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried and how it fails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging CSV files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331613/merging-csv-files)

Answer (score 1):

if all csv's has the same columns, simply:

```
# Original CSV
$csv = import-csv c:\temp.csv

# 2nd CSV
$csv2 = import-csv c:\temp2.csv

# As simple as:
$csv += $csv2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import all CSV's in the current folder you can do something like the following:

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv | % { Import-Csv $_ }
```

Answer (score -1):

start by copying the first file to an output file.

then see this (question, answer):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076557/1331076
it shows you how to remove the first line from a file.
you would have to modify it, so instead of replacing your existing file, you `Add-Content` to the output file.